# Determine Mono vs Stereo for pcm alaw

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop

Self-taught c# programmer and have been searching google for a solution to find out if pcm alaw is mono or stereo with no luck. I've written this simple code which seems to work but looking for advice if this is a suitable way to determine the channel information. Any advice or direction is appreciated.

```
private bool IsStereo
        {
            get
            {
                int i = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < m_Samples.Length / 2; j++)
                {
                    float left = m_Samples[j];
                    float right = m_Samples[j + 1];
                    if (left.Equals(right))
                        i++;
                }
                return i == Samples / 2;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you load the data from a file? Did that file include metadata describing the dat in it?

Comment: The .al file was created using ffmpeg and only contains a collection of float[] values.

Comment: The question in its current form cannot be answered. Before writing any code, you should be very clear what you are trying to do, for self-taught or not. For example, what is the source format of your audio? "created using ffmpeg" is rather ambiguous and you must share more (like which ffmpeg command you used). Knowing the format makes it possible to interpret the bytes, much better than just "a collection of float[] values". File formats were defined to organize data in the right places.

Comment: @LexLi The command used was ffmpeg -i inputsong.mp3 outputsong.al.